# Lorentz model imaginary and real parts

Tags: electromagnetism, optics, waves, electromagnetic-radiation, resonance

I'm having some problems with the definition of the real and imaginary parts of the Lorentz model, we start from the definition of the permitivity $$\chi=\chi'+i\chi''=\frac{\omega_p^2}{\omega^2-\omega^2-i\omega \gamma}=\omega_p^2\frac{\omega_0^2-\omega^2}{(\omega_0^2-\omega^2)^2+(\omega \gamma)^2}+i\omega_p^2\frac{\omega \gamma}{(\omega_0^2-\omega^2)^2+(\omega \gamma)^2}$$

So we have,

\begin{align}
\chi'=\omega_p^2\frac{\omega_0^2-\omega^2}{(\omega_0^2-\omega^2)^2+(\omega \gamma)^2} \quad \xrightarrow{} \quad \text{Refractive index}\\
\chi''=\omega_p^2\frac{\omega \gamma}{(\omega_0^2-\omega^2)^2+(\omega \gamma)^2}\quad \xrightarrow{} \quad \text{Absorption} \qquad  \,
\end{align}

This results are correct, you can see them in different sites for example [MIT-Lorentz-Oscillator](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-007-electromagnetic-energy-from-motors-to-lasers-spring-2011/readings/MIT6_007S11_lorentz.pdf), and as we expect, for the absorption we get a Lorentzian, and for the refractive index we get a dispersive distribution, as is illustrated at the image,[image]
In the image are represented the permeabilities but are proportional. My doubt comes when if you plot the before expressions $\chi(\omega)$ you don't get the Lorentzian or the dispersive plots, in fact $\chi'$ is a even function, and $\chi''$ is a odd function, that doesnt match with the linked image... And I don't know what I'm doing wrong

Comment: What does it look like when you try to plot them? The parity of the function is irrelevant because we only consider $\omega > 0$.

Comment: That was my error, I was looking the function around zero, but we are interested in the part around $\omega_0$, my confusion comes from that the imaginary plot with $\omega_0 \rightarrow 0$ is almost exactly a dispersive plot around zero. Thanks!

Comment: The functions may seem as if their parity was wrong, however the submitted picture does not show the functions around $\omega=0$. We're looking at high values of $\omega$. If you were to look at negative values, you'd see that the parity is actually correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah, the imaginary part (loss) is supposed to be an odd function. For negative frequency, you have gain. Try plotting it!